# Tilemap shader confusion

Tags: unity, shaders

I am trying to setup a system for utilizing uvs to tile a texture and reduce draw calls. I'm using Unity. I create a texture which records the x index of the tile from a tileset into the red channel and try to use it in the shader. Here's the shader code:

```
        sampler2D _TilemapTex;
        sampler2D _MainTex;         
        float _MaxIndex;
        vector _TilesetDim;
        vector _TilemapDim;

        struct vertexInput {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 texcoord: TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct vertexOutput {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            float2 texcoord: TEXCOORD0;
        };
        vertexOutput vert(vertexInput v)
        {
            vertexOutput output;

            output.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            output.texcoord = v.texcoord;
            return output;
        }
        float4 SampleMap(float2 texcoord) {
            return tex2D(_TilemapTex, texcoord).r * 255;
        }
        float4 GetUv(int index, float2 texcoord) {

            int xpos = index;
            int ypos = _TilesetDim.y - 1;
            float2 uv = float2(xpos/_TilesetDim.x, ypos);
            float xoffset = frac(texcoord.x * _TilemapDim.x) / _TilesetDim.x;
            float yoffset = frac(texcoord.y * _TilemapDim.y) / _TilesetDim.y;
            uv += float2(xoffset, yoffset);
            float4 main = tex2D(_MainTex, uv);
            return main;
        }
        float4 frag(vertexOutput i) : SV_Target
        {
            int index = tex2D(_TilemapTex, i.texcoord).r * 255;

            return GetUv(index, i.texcoord);
        }`
```

I'm a beginner with shaders so maybe I'm missing something simple. Here's the result:
[image]

It looks interesting but I expected it to fill entire tiles.

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking. All you're telling us is that you're encoding the x-index of a tile into the red channel of a texture and then <code> produces <result> and that it's not right. I am not going to read through <code> to try and figure out what the heck its doing unless I know what it's doing *wrong.* You said you "expect it to fill entire tiles" but that in no way relates to "encoding the x-index in the red channel" from a grammatical perspective.

Comment: I have a tilemap where each tile has a type and a tileset atlas which holds the graphics for each tile type. I pass the shader a texture that represents which tile from the tileset should be on what tile in the tilemap by setting the index in the red channel then I try to convert it into uv space. I'm using the code from here for the frag shader: http://www.connorhollis.com/fast-tilemap-shader/ The only difference is that I don't use the y index in the tileset. Each square should be only one type, but in the image you can see that there are some weird transitions going on.

Comment: Shouldn't tile maps be reducing drawcalls to begin with? Have you checked with the framedebugger or renderdoc?

Comment: [See here](https://i.imgur.com/YfRxnBI.png) Tilemaps are batched, what performance are you after?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The problem was that the texture I used for sampling wasn't point filtered so that's where the weirdness came from.